# My JS variable loading before element exists, so they are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a script to manipulate the DOM in Wordpress.
My problem is that when creating the variables they appear empty because my script loads before the elements exist.
How can I solve this?
I have this little test that although it says the element exists, when I check the variable in the console it returns 0.

Many thanks.

```html
var el2 = jQuery(".slick-slide");

if (el2 > 0) {
  console.log('element does NOT exist in DOM');
} else {

  console.log('element exists in DOM');
}
```

Comment: Use document ready or $function?

Comment: You need to compare `el2.length` to `0`, not the whole jQuery object.

Comment: I just did, still says "element exists in DOM" then the var is 0

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you do this like

```
$(function() {
var el2 = jQuery(".slick-slide");

if (el2 > 0) {
  console.log('element does NOT exist in DOM');
} else {

  console.log('element exists in DOM');
}
});
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Not adding the div

jQuery(function() {
var slides = jQuery(".slick-slide").length - jQuery(".slick-cloned").length
var columnsWidth = (100 / slides)-1.7
var a = ""
var last = slides - 1
for (var i = 0; i < slides ; i++) {
  
  a += jQuery(".para-testar").append('<div class="elementor-column elementor-top-column elementor-element teste teste-'+ i +'" style="width:'+ columnsWidth +'%;"></div>')
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

Try create variables when document is ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var el2 = jQuery(".slick-slide");

....
```

Comment: not working still :(